# How to discern, whether Ansible runs in color mode?

Tags: ansible

I'm implementing a role, which calls an external application (using `shell`-module). That application can color its output to make it easier on human eyes.

I'd like to enable -- or disable -- that coloring depending on whether Ansible's own coloring of output is enabled, either because its stdout is a TTY, or because `force_color` is set.

But how do I detect this? There is no `ansible_force_color`, for example...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`config`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/config_lookup.html) lookup to access Ansible configuration:

```yaml
# playbook.yaml
---
- name: Check the colors
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Check if ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR setting is set
      debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('config', 'ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR') | bool }}"
```

Comment: Ok, that checks, whether the colors are _forced_. What about the other case -- where the colors are enabled simply because stdout is a TTY?